# Не срабатывает событие change изменения (jquery)

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, такой вопрос, проверяю на изменения группу инпутов. Через событие change.
Часть из них меняется пользователем при заполнении в самом поле, а другая часть меняется путем изменения value по средством кода.

При изменения непосредствено в поле событие срабатывает, а вот через изменния с заменой value нет.

Вот пример о чем я: http://jsfiddle.net/atach/UtSeV/

Пожскажите, может не то событие я использую?

Comment: почему prop('value') ? чем $(this).val() плох ?

Comment: делайте trigger change - само по себе изменение DOM не вызывает события
http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/UtSeV/1/

Comment: Большое спасибо за trigger change  ....
По поводу почему prop, просто дело привычки уже .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Событие корректно работает именно так, как ему и положено работать, т.е. вызывается после **onblur** в случае, если **value** была изменена.

Полагаю, Вам нужен [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".check").change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});

$("#btntest").click(function() {
    $("input[name=inp2]").val("123").change();
});
```